# How to schedule Server Backup/Recovery process

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-backup

I have two Windows servers located in different geographic location. One server is used as file server (*i.e. shared location and have a directory tree with around 60 Gb of files*).

I need to have the same directory tree on another server in another city and keep those files in sync. They don't need to be 'live' sync (*i.e. it could be a few hours or a day diff but they should be kind of 'close' content*). There are a few utilities that could sync files but I want to start with **Windows Server Backup and Restore utility**.

### My Plan

My plan is to create a backup once a day and then restore it on another server. I think that way they will be in 'close' sync. Since the destination is remote/network server it will erase previous backups and I will have only one backup at a time and this will be fine. I see it creates a folder called `WindowsImageBackup` on target server.

**Question:** I know how to setup and schedule backup procedure but could I setup automatic *i.e. Scheduled Restore process on destination server*?

- I mean *e.g. I will backup at midnight (it'll take a few hours) and in a few hours destination server will start automatic restore process from that latest backup*.
- If this is supported, I'm trying to figure out how to do it so I can automate the recovery and scheduled it accordingly to occur after the backup and copy completes.

Comment: I don't have time to test, if you are trying to automate wbadmin recovery of a UNC path backed up file backup, something with this syntax should work: `wbadmin start recovery -version:MM/DD/YYYY-hh:mm -itemtype:File -items:<RecoveryPath> -recursive -BackupTargt:\\<Server>\<Share>\<Folder> -RecoveryTarget:<RecoverPath>` but you'll want to use the `-quiet` parameter and you'll also need to figure out a way to dynamically get the  version identified set to a variable to put into the command accordingly... `wbadmin get versions -backuptarget:\\<Server>\<Share>\<Folder>| findstr /i "identifier"`

Comment: Checkout Bvckup2. well worth the few bucks.
Task Schedule a robocopy for the free version

Comment: Well I appreciate your suggestions. I will play with wbadmin and see if I could make it to work. Regarding version of backup I don’t think it should be an issue in my case since when I am doing backup remotely (my case) it keeps only one latest version.

Comment: I played with robocopy and it did the job. Thanks a lot for suggestions. Ticket could be closed

Comment: Well .... thanks for your help!! It works great! The only disadvantage is that in case I have a lot of files in a directory it takes days to copy to server. Any other idea instead of robocopy when I have a million of files? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I should use tar utility instead of robocopy in that case? I can’t wait for 2 days until it finishes

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help me. You are correct in your assumptions. I'm copying 2 folders. Both are almost the same size ~ 2.5 Gb. First one has ~136K files and second one has around a million. The second one is  the issue. Those files are .dat files. This is my current script: @echo off
SET SRC1=\\vhabosapp3gen\FS_REPO
SET DST1=\\vhapthsql12gen.v04.med.va.gov\FS_REPO
SET LOG=\\vhabosfpc1gen\lims\LimsLZ\tools\logs\Boston_Pts_SDMS.log
SET OPT=/S /NP /R:5 /LOG+:%Log% /TS /FP
SET CMD1=robocopy %SRC1% %DST1%  %OPT%
%CMD1%
I am using Cygwin as well. How could I tar/zip?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, I mean that batch should take of tar or zip on *source* server and destination server and be removed at the end ( or at least overwritten by a new tar or zip). Could you please give me an example using my current batch file I pasted above? If batch is not a good choice for that maybe better to use python? Because anyway after using robocopy I run python script to verify that everything was copied . I do it by comparing a number of files in source and destination folders. Thanks again. Appreciate it ..

Comment: 1. both source files/folders change very frequently hence I'm copying it at night. That time they are not changing. Actually to those 1 million get added a few hundreds daily. There are a few of subdirectories (3-4 levels) under \FS_REPO.
2. Well not sure about it. I don't think I could leave it archived because the reason of those files is that they are used when application request some data and I assume they should be 'ready to use' as is. Actually this is a web app which stores data at \FS

Comment: Would this scripted solution make sense or be something you thing you could test or be applicable (https://content.spiceworksstatic.com/service.community/p/post_attachments/0000173583/57ee67d2/attached_file/copy_script.txt)? I found it per a post on https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1691932-fastest-way-to-copy-millions-of-little-files-fastcopy and it seems to make RC work a lot better with tons of files and such. Otherwise, it sounds like you'd need to compress all files to a single zip file keeping structure & then set it up to extract same structure on destination & overwrite, correct?

Comment: I will check the link you provided. I am planning to verify the workflow of tar and copy. Here is my plan before I implement it in production:1. create a folder e.g. d:\mytarS. Create some sub folders and files on source server. 2. tar this folder e.g. s.tar 3. Copy this s.tar to destination server e.g. d:\mytarD\s.tar. 4. Create structure d:\mytarD same as I have on source server under d:\mytarS. 5. Open s.tar. 6. Add some files to source and repeat the process. I want to verify that workflow works as expected. First I will try it in batch. If I hit an issue I will try python script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79724/discussion-between-susik-and-pimp-juice-it).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue before and suggest you use backup tools like robocopy or gs richcopy which i preferred and using, it has many option and help me certainly in scheduling copying. read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS_RichCopy_360#Supported_Operating_Systems

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](//meta.superuser.com/a/5330) paying particular attention to the items in *bold*. After doing so, please [edit your answer](//superuser.com/posts/1350438/edit) so it follows the guidelines.